# Check for default constraints

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is there a way to select all constraints or check if a default constraint exists before deleting it in Sql Ce? For example in Sql Server you could select from sys.default_constraints..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174156.aspx